# Material-UI Grid System - limit 2 items per row

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way to limit grid items to 2 per row and make the items in each row to take up all available space? I'm using ReactJS and MaterialUI Core.

This is the main grid:

```
<Grid
  container
  direction="row"
  alignContent="center"
  alignItems="center"
  wrap="wrap"
>
  <Grid item className={classes.cardDesign}>
    {showTags ? <Tags /> : null}
  </Grid>
  <Grid item className={classes.cardDesign}>
    {showReactions ? <Reactions /> : null}
  </Grid>
  <Grid item className={classes.cardDesign}>
    {showEmojiStats ? <EmojiStats /> : null}
  </Grid>
  <Grid item className={classes.cardDesign}>
    {showFilter ? <Filter /> : null}
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And these are the grid items:

```
<div className={classes.root}>
  <Card className={classes.cardDesign}>
    <CardContent>
      <Typography
        className={classes.title}
        color="textSecondary"
        gutterBottom
      >
        Filters
      </Typography>
      <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
        be{bull}nev{bull}o{bull}lent
      </Typography>
      <Typography className={classes.pos} color="textSecondary">
        adjective
      </Typography>
      <Typography variant="body2" component="p">
        well meaning and kindly.
        <br />
        {'"a benevolent smile"'}
      </Typography>
    </CardContent>
    <CardActions>
      <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
    </CardActions>
  </Card>
</div>
```

Comment: It will be great to show code

Comment: @mw509 just edited, see code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the Grid property => xs, sm, md, lg, and xl.
which allow to create column size depending on the screen size.

I made a stackblitz with your example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-boilerplate-scalabw-cc3zyh?file=index.js

Comment: Thank you! This worked, however, is there a way to make the grid reorder everything to what is only visible? So if tags 1 and 3 were only visible, those two would be side by side?

Comment: sure! i just updated the stackblitz you can check and try it by changing the value from true to false to your booleans.
i moved the Grid element inside your Component, this way it's moving dynamically!

Comment: Thank you for that it works! Just one last thing, is there a way to have those Grid Items go under each after they come back. So if there are 4 grid items, and I hide Grid Item 1 and 3, so there are only 2 and 4 left, but then I unhide 1 and 3, is there a way to display the final grid as 2,4,1,3 instead of the normal 1,2,3,4?

Comment: i think the best solution to make that would be to build some kind of array with all your components and then push into this array a new element everytime a props change

Comment: Please check out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61865549/component-not-being-recognised-in-array

Answer (score 4):

The Grid system of Material-UI gives you exactly that.

The general idea is that your workspace (the width of the screen) is divided into 12 columns/containers, and each child can consume up to % of it's parent container. You can decide on the width of the columns using a 12/X system of classes, so if you want a 2-split you can use `6 | 6`, if you prefer to have a 6-split you can use `2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2`, and you can also play with other numbers (for example you can have `6 | 3 | 3` or `4 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 2`. As longs as the sum gets you 12 - you are all good.

There are 5 grid breakpoints that you can use: `xs`, `sm`, `md`, `lg`, `xl`, they give you more flexibility when you need to have different layouts for different screen sizes:

- xs - default
- sm - min width `600px`
- md - min width `960px`
- lg - min width `1280px`
- xl - min width `1920px`

This system gives you the flexibility you set a grid that on small screen has 2 columns and on large screens have 4 columns, and on extra-large screens will have all 6 items available in 1 row:

```
<Grid container>
    <Grid item xs={6} lg={3} xl={2}>...</Grid>
    <Grid item xs={6} lg={3} xl={2}>...</Grid>
    <Grid item xs={6} lg={3} xl={2}>...</Grid>
    <Grid item xs={6} lg={3} xl={2}>...</Grid>
    <Grid item xs={6} lg={3} xl={2}>...</Grid>
    <Grid item xs={6} lg={3} xl={2}>...</Grid>
</Grid>
```

It's also easy to create other layouts using this system, for example if you need a 2:10 split (for a left-side menu) you can use:

```
<Grid container>
    <Grid item xs={2}>...</Grid>
    <Grid item xs={10}>...</Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for the info! However, I have tried this and the actual grid items do not take all of available horizontal space for some reason. What would be the problem?

Comment: Please create a working example (you can use https://codesandbox.io for that). Otherwise it will be hard to understand the specific issue you are facing.

Comment: Sorry I just had a configuration issue, but this explained a lot of it thank you. Is there a way to make the grid reorder everything to what is only visible? So if tags 1 and 3 were only visible, those two would be side by side?

Comment: If the answer is correct, please take the time to accept it. Regarding the reordering of the grid - I'm not sure I'm following you here.

Comment: What I am trying to do is have cards that reorder and place themselves on the same row if one or more of the Grid items are disabled.

If you look at this link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-boilerplate-scalabw-zuckbg?file=index.js I have disabled 2 of the grid items but it looks awkward. What I want is to have them on the same line.

Comment: The grid-item will occupy the space, because this is what it's job :-) if you don't want to display that grid-item, you can decide not to render it based on the variable that you have: `{showTags ? <Grid item xs={6}><Tags /></Grid> : null}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213935/discussion-between-nathaneal-varghese-and-dekel).