# how to use Grid into another file in React material-ui

Tags: reactjs, grid, material-ui

I use React js.I want to use Grid, but I can't in this particular case.
I have a component called CardComponent.js
The problem is that I use the map function. I don't know how to use Grid.

```
import React from "react";

const rows = [
  {
    id: 7,
    email: "michael.lawson@reqres.in",
    first_name: "Michael",
    last_name: "Lawson"
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    email: "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in",
    first_name: "Lindsay",
    last_name: "Ferguson"
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    email: "michael.lawson@reqres.in",
    first_name: "Michael",
    last_name: "Lawson"
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    email: "lindsay.ferguson@reqres.in",
    first_name: "Lindsay",
    last_name: "Ferguson"
  }
];

const ElevatedCardHeader = () =>
  rows.map(row => (
    <Card className={"MuiElevatedCard--01"}>
      <CardHeader
        className={"MuiCardHeader-root"}
        title={row.id}
        subheader={row.email}
        classes={{
          title: "MuiCardHeader-title",
          subheader: "MuiCardHeader-subheader"
        }}
      />
      <CardContent className={"MuiCardContent-root"}>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <Grid container>
              <Grid container justify="space-evenly">
                <label>first_name:</label>
                <label>{row.first_name}</label>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Divider light />
          </Grid>

          <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <Grid container>
              <Grid container justify="space-evenly">
                <label>last_name:</label>
                <label>{row.last_name}</label>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Divider light />
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  ));
export default ElevatedCardHeader;
```

How can I display 2 cards per row using Grid?Currently, 1 card is displayed in each row.
Here you can see my [codesandbox.io](http://codesandbox.io/s/elevatedcardheader-01-3i49l?file=/src/index.js)
Thank you in advance for your help and guidance

Comment: Each `<Card>` element inside your map should get inside it's own `<Grid item>` element with the `xs={6}`. Check my explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61815605/material-ui-grid-system-limit-2-items-per-row

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Material-UI Grid System - limit 2 items per row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61815605/material-ui-grid-system-limit-2-items-per-row)

Comment: Note that the `<ElevatedCardHeader>` component should be wrapped with `<Grid container>`.

Comment: @Dekel I use map so I don't understand. Please edit my CodeSandbox if possible

Comment: When you use map - each element is the result of the map-function. In your case - instead of `<Card>` you should return `<Grid item xs={6}><Card>...`.

Comment: @Dekel But I designed the card and I need it. Please tell me what to do

Comment: @Dekel How can I update the question so that everyone can answer???

Comment: I didn't say remove the card. I said you need to wrap it with Grid-item

Comment: In general - you need to understand how the Grid-System works (I believe you have good explanation for that in my answer). Once you understand this - you are good to go.

Comment: @Dekel I did this but I get an error. Can you test on my codeSandbox?

Comment: Provide a link to the new codesandbox with the error

Comment: @Dekel https://codesandbox.io/s/elevatedcardheader-01-3i49l?file=/src/CardComponent.js

Comment: @Dekel what happened

Comment: @Dekel You wasted a lot of my time. The answer was one word https://stackoverflow.com/q/61849456/12219516

Comment: Not sue why you decided that I wasted a lot of your time. In my answer you can see that all `<Grid item>'s` elements are wrapped with a `<Grid container>`.