# Component Not Being Recognised In Array

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to dynamically render elements however when I try and splice the component from the array it does not get removed.

```
const [cardsInGrid, setCards] = React.useState([]);

const [showReactions, setShowReactions] = React.useState(false);

const onReactionsClick = () => {
    setShowReactions(!showReactions);
  };

useEffect(() => {
    if (showReactions) {
      setCards(cardsInGrid.concat(<Reactions />));
    } else if (!showReactions) {
      console.log(cardsInGrid);
      var index = cardsInGrid.indexOf(<Reactions />);
      console.log(index);
      if (index > -1) {
        setCards(cardsInGrid.splice(index, 1));
        console.log(cardsInGrid);
      }
    }
  }, [showReactions]);
```

The concat in the first if statement works but the console.log(index) returns -1 each time.  is a component that I have.

EDIT:
Array of components

```
const componentList = [
    { id: "tags", component: Tags },
    { id: "reactions", component: Reactions },
    { id: "emojistats", component: EmojiStats },
    { id: "filters", component: Filter },
  ];
```

How would I render these components if I have a predefined array?

Comment: `concat` joins two arrays. But you're passing a component to it. Are you sure it works?

Comment: @Kraylog Yes it indeed passes a component and renders it on the screen (although that code is not shown)

Comment: Do you push anything other than a `<Reactions />` JSX literal? Logging the array shows it's an array of objects. `array::indexOf` also uses strict equality, so as long as you're pushing in new instances of react components it will never return anything other than -1. Is there some other value you can use to correlate a specific element in the array, like the index? (*You're likely rendering these in an `array::map` somewhere, right?*). Maybe don't put `Reactions` in the array and just conditionally render it?

Comment: @DrewReese I want it to be dynamically rendered because I want the widgets to be rendered in a specific order. I have other components as well but the order is important and afaik the best way to execute that is by adding these components to an array and then rendering that. However, if I was to put something else there instead of the component, I don't know what else I would use. Do  you have any suggestions?

Comment: In scenarios like this I'd split up the array into content before & after Reactions. Another pattern is to use an array of config objects that are mapped, where the config could be something simple like `{ id: 'someId', component: Reactions }`, then use `const index = cardsInGrid.findIndex(el => el.id === searchId)`. Maybe the config has an "orderIndex" or "category" properties you could use to help enforce order/organization.

Comment: @DrewReese Could you show me a quick example or maybe edit your answer?
Check my edit for the array of config objects that I added as per your comment.

Comment: @NathanealVarghese Sure, added an **EDIT** to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array::splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

`splice` mutates the array in-place, but react state works by returning new objects and array references.

[array::filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Array filter can return the new array you need. Using the second parameter of the filter function you can filter all array elements' index that isn't equal to that of the one you want to remove from the array.

> The `splice()` method changes the contents of an array by removing or
>   replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements in place.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (showReactions) {
    setCards(cardsInGrid.concat(<Reactions />));
  } else if (!showReactions) {
    console.log(cardsInGrid);
    var index = cardsInGrid.indexOf(<Reactions />);
    console.log(index);
    if (index > -1) {
      setCards(cardsInGrid.filter((_, i) => i !== index);
      console.log(cardsInGrid);
    }
  }
}, [showReactions]);
```

**EDIT:** Using a component config array

```
/**
 * External source of truth
 * Could be global variable like this or passed as prop to rendering component
 */
const componentList = [
  { id: "tags", component: Tags },
  { id: "reactions", component: Reactions },
  { id: "emojiStats", component: EmojiStats },
  { id: "filters", component: Filters }
];

export default function App() {
  // cardsInGrid displays current filtered component list
  const [cardsInGrid, setCardsInGrid] = useState(componentList);
  const [showReactions, setShowReactions] = React.useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showReactions) {
      // Filter Reactions component out
      setCardsInGrid(componentList.filter(({ id }) => id !== "reactions"));
    } else {
      // Reset to full component list array
      setCardsInGrid(componentList);
    }
  }, [showReactions]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => setShowReactions(r => !r)}>
          {showReactions ? "Hide" : "Show"} Reactions
        </button>
      </div>

      {cardsInGrid.map(({ id, component: Component }) => (
        <Component key={id} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Filter Component List]

***NOTE:*** If you need to filter by more than just a single component then a generalized solution could be a stored map of component config id's to filter by and using array::includes

```
const [filterBy, setFilterBy] = useState({});

// logic to handle adding/removing filters by name
// i.e. filterBy = { reactions: 'reactions', ...etc }

useEffect(() => {
  const filters = Object.values(filterBy);
  if (filters.length) {
    // Filter components out if id matches anything in filter
    setCardsInGrid(componentList.filter(({ id }) => filters.include(id)));
  } else {
    // Reset to full component list array
    setCardsInGrid(componentList);
  }
}, [filterBy]);
```

Comment: This does not work. Like I said in my initial post, the actual index returns -1, even though there are objects in and being added to the array.